# strcat in C error segmentation

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char tab[2]={"12"};
  FILE *outfile;
  char *outname = "/home/dir/";
  printf("%s", strcat(outname,tab));
  outfile = fopen(strcat(outname,btab), "w");
  if (!outfile) {
    printf("There was a problem opening %s for writing\n", outname);
  }
}
```

I have this error: Segmentation Fault.

How can I fix it?

Comment: My idea for you is to use proper indentation.

Comment: @H2CO3: if you're going to fix `main`, might as well make it `int main(void)`.

Comment: @Mat why? using empty parentheses is just fine (and IMHO looks way better).

Comment: @H2CO3: `int main()` is a function that can take any number of arguments (in C, not C++). `int main(void)` takes not arguments. That and `int main(int, char**)` are the only two standard main signatures.

Comment: @H2CO3 Don't edit what might be relevant to the OP's problem.

Comment: @Mat int main() also takes no arguments and is equivalent to int main(void).

Comment: @H2CO3 If there is a mistake or a misconception in the OP's code, point it out instead of editing it. Otherwise, it can cause confusion.

Comment: @Tibor OK, I'll do it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least two errors:

```
char tab[2] = {"12"};
```

You'd better use `tab[3]` or even better `tab[]` -- you need one extra char for the terminating NUL character.

Also,

```
char *outname = "etc...";
```

creates a constant string in the data segment of the executable -- it can't be overwritten, since `strcat` is using its first parameter to concatenate the two strings. So when `strcat()` tries to do so, it segfaults. Use

```
char outname[50]; // something big enough
strcpy(outname, "/home/dir");
```

instead.

Comment: If he literally codes `char outname[] = "/home/dir/";` he will still have problems when he then calls `strcat(outname, ...)`

Comment: @mah why? You are not right -- when one uses char[] instead of char *, the compiler generates a string that is not constant and can be overwritten!

Comment: @H2CO3 - yes, it does, and the size of what it the compiler generates is sized to hold the contents of the string constant, and nothing more. Since `strcat()` wants to append to the string, and since no space was allocated to append into, you'll be overwriting something else.

Answer (score 1):

`outname` is a string literal and string literals are not modifiable. Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**outname** is **Const pointer** so once you have entered some thing in it, you **can't modify** it.

However if you want to copy things in it, make a char array of the size equal to tab[] array because here the size of string to be copied is known. Most of the time char pointers like OUTNAME are used when you are taking input from a user once and you don't know how long that input will be.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
char *outname = "/home/dir/";
```

outname is a string literal and hence when used with strcat, it does not have enough length to hold the concatenated string.This results in segmentation fault.

Same is the case had you declared it as below,

```
char outname[] = "/home/dir/";
```

The solution for this to declare the size of the outname big enough to hold the concatenated string.

```
char outname[80] = "/home/dir/";
```